# how uses fine secret static api keys with sveltekit and vercel

Tags: deployment, environment-variables, vercel, sveltekit

The situation is as follows:
I have created an application with sveltekit.

It needs to use a static API key in order to work.

I am familiar with the possibilities of using environment variables with sveltekit

*$env/dynamic/private*
*$env/dynamic/public*
*$env/static/private*
*$env/static/public*

On the other hand, vercel provides a special section explaining  how to enter the environment variables when deploying a project., which according to what I read, has special prefixes for dynamic environment variables like the git commit id, etc...

The only thing I am looking for is that my API_key can be secure and not available on the client side. and also available for use on the server side once the page is deployed.

as I said before, my apiKey, is a simple static string and I can't understand why it is so complex to use that when deploying it when in local it works perfect and fast.  :'(

I am currently doing the following:

in the `routes` directory i have a file `+page.server.js` with the following code:

`const apiKey = "somePrivateApiKeyNoLiteralxD"

export const load = () => {

```
return { secretApi: apiKey }
```

}`

and in my +page.svelte file i have the following lines:

`export let data const apiKey = data.secretApi`

and well, in local, i can use that apiKey and don't have no security errors or anything like that.

but when i deploy the app in vercel, even if add my api key in the environment  variables section config prev to deploy..

when I test the app it does not work :(

I read millions of times the sveltekit documentation, the vercel documentation, watched videos and everything but I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have tried before other solutions like using the alternative of `secret.server.js` in the **lib** directory, and vercel didn't allow me to deploy it, because it exposed sensitive client side information...

I look forward to finding the answer and sharing my application so that it can be used.

before I have tried the solutions of consuming the apiKEY from an `.env` file and also the other option where you can create a `server` file in the `lib` directory, but none of them works with svelte.